# Image not styling anymore after declaring html5

Tags: css, html

After putting in my !DOCTYPE html at the beginning of my page, one of images isn't changing style anymore. The other images are but this particular one isn't. What am I doing wrong? here is the code:

The image:

```
<p id="Index">
        <img src="../Web Site/Pictures/Pic1.jpg" id="Pic1">
        ...
</p>
```

The picture is inside a p element.

The CSS of the pic:

```
#Pic1 {

    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    height: 250;
    width: 200;
    }
```

The CSS of the paragraph:

```
#Index {

    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: "Papyrus";
    color: #22b14c;
    }
```

Comment: in the width and height you should have `px` like so: `height:250px`

Answer (score 1):

Change to this and see if it works

```
#Pic1 {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    height: 250px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: please accept he's answer so you will be able to ask later on and get responses.